# complex absolute value equations

Tags: linear-algebra, absolute-value

How on earth does one solve this problem?

I know that to solve abs value equations we have to consider both the negative and postive possibilities, but the constant (6) makes this a little more challenging

$|x-8|=|2-x|-6$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Don't get scared by the constant $-6$. Just consider all possibilities for the absolute values.

Answer (score 3):

Split it into three parts:

- $x<2$
- $2\leq x\leq 8$
- $8<x$

Note that the three parts follow straight forward from the equation, $x=2$ and $x=8$ are the points where $|2-x|$ and $|x-8|$ flip sign. Now you can inspect each part seperately, such that you can drop the absolute values:

- If $x<2$ then $|x-8|=8-x$ and $|2-x|=2-x$, so the equation becomes:
  $$8-x=2-x-6 \iff 8-x=-4-x,$$
  which has no solution.
- If $2\leq x\leq 8$ then $|x-8|=8-x$ and $|2-x|=x-2$, so the equation becomes:
  $$8-x=x-2-6 \iff 8-x=x-8,$$
  which has solution $x=8$.
- If $8<x$ then $|x-8|=x-8$ and $|2-x|=x-2$, so the equation becomes:
  $$x-8=x-2-6 \iff x-8=x-8,$$
  which is true for every $x$.

Concluding, $|x-8|=|2-x|-6$ for $x\geq8$.

**Edit** to answer Johns comment:

By definition $|y|=\begin{cases}y\ \mbox{ if }\ y\geq0\\ -y\ \mbox{ if }\ y<0\end{cases}$. So when we look at $|x-8|$ for $x<2$, we can use this definition as follows:
$$x<2 \Rightarrow x-8<-6 \Rightarrow |x-8|=-(x-8)=8-x.$$
The same reasoning is used in the rest of the answer.

Comment: Ok i understand your working, but how did you go from the solution of x=8 to the final answer of "x is greater than or equal to 8"?

Comment: Hey! In Part 3 ($8<x$), the equation becomes $x-8=x-8$, which is true for every $x$. I ended that part with _which is true for every_ $x$. However, we were considering Part 3, so what I mean there is: _which is true for every_ $x$ _in Part 3_. That is $x>8$. Combined with the solution of Part 2 ($x=8$), this gives the conclusion: $x\geq8$. I hope this clarifies things.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. But what i dont get is when you say "if x < 2 then |x-8| = 8-x. Why does this swap round? Also the same thing for the other parts.

Comment: I've added the explanation to the answer.

Comment: Ok thank you. In th middle section, you say that if 2≤x≤8 then |x-8|=8-x, but I do not agree with this statement. If x=8 (which is included in the above range) then 8-8 = 0, so the part inside the absolute value should not be flipped (because |y|=y for 0 ≤ y). So why have you flipped the expression? Thanks.

Comment: When $y=0$, it does not matter whether you state $|y|=-y$ or $|y|=y$, since $-0=0$. So when $x=8$, then $|x-8|$ equals zero, whether you flip it or not. To see that if $2\leq x\leq 8$, then $|x-8|=8-x$, try other values of $x$ instead of only 8, and you'll see that it is correct. To gain more insight into the behavior of the absolute value, I'd suggest reading [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) and play around with it, plot it for different arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Since $|x-8|+6$ and $|2-x|$ are both nonnegative, you can square both sides of $|x-8|+6=|2-x|$ obtaining the *equivalent* equation
$$
x^2-16x+64+12|x-8|+36=4-4x+x^2
$$
that becomes
$$
12|x-8|=12x-96
$$
or else $|x-8|=x-8$. Of course this is valid for every $x\ge8$.